# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly/Sorting Array issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Having an issue with a certain part of the code (I am new to coding and have tried looking through StackOverflow for help):

```
def totalRainfall (rainfall):
    totalRain = 0
    month = 0
    while month < len(rainfall):
        totalRain = rainfall[month] + totalRain
        month += 1

    return totalRain
```

TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

I've tried multiple ways of changing the code to make it a string explicitly as it still giving me various issues.

I'm also having a hard time enhancing the code to sort the array in ascending order and displays the values it contains.

The full code is here:

```
def main ():
    rainfall = rainInput ()
    totalRain = totalRainfall (rainfall)
    average_Rainfall = averageRainfall (totalRain)
    highestMonth, highestMonthly = highestMonthNumber (rainfall)
    lowestMonth, lowestMonthly = lowestMonthNumber (rainfall)
    print #this is for spacing output
    print ('The total rainfall for the year was: ' +str(totalRain) + ' inche(s)')
    print #this is for spacing output
    print ('The average rainfall for the year was: ' +str(average_Rainfall) +\
          ' inche(s)') 
    print #this is for spacing in output
    print ('The highest amount of rain was', highestMonthly, 'in' , highestMonth)
    print #this is for spacing in output
    print ('The lowest amount of rain was', lowestMonthly, 'in' , lowestMonth)

def rainInput ():
    rainfall = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August'\
    ,'September','October','November','December']
    month = 0
    while month < len(rainfall):
        rainfall[month] = input ('Please enter the amount for month ' + str\
        (month + 1) + ': ')
        month += 1

    return rainfall

def totalRainfall (rainfall):
    totalRain = 0
    month = 0
    while month < len(rainfall):
        totalRain = rainfall[month] + totalRain
        month += 1

    return totalRain

def averageRainfall (totalRain):
    average_Rainfall = totalRain / 12

    return average_Rainfall

def highestMonthNumber (rainfall):
    month = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August'\
                ,'September','October','November','December']
    highestMonthly = 0
    for m, n in enumerate(rainfall):
        if n > highestMonthly:
            highestMonthly = n
            highestMonth = m

    return month[highestMonth], highestMonthly

def lowestMonthNumber (rainfall):
    month = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August'\
                ,'September','October','November','December']
    lowestMonthly = 0
    for m, n in enumerate(rainfall):
        if n < lowestMonthly:
            lowestMonthly = n
            lowestMonth = m

    return month[lowestMonth], lowestMonthly

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total rainfall as the sum of the numbers per month, simply use `sum()` on the list of ints. But as your error suggests, you have a list of strings, which you explicitly have to convert.

Something along the lines of

```
def totalRainfall (rainfall):
    return sum([int(x) for x in rainfall])
```

The problem with your list being strings will continue to be problematic for you, so as a quick fix, I suggest you change this line

```
    rainfall[month] = input ('Please enter the amount for month ' + str\
    (month + 1) + ': ')
```

to

```
    rainfall[month] = int(input('Please enter the amount for month ' + str\
    (month + 1) + ': '))
```

That way your list contains only numbers and all your other comparisons will work.

You should also add this initialization in your `lowestMonthNumber` function to avoid `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lowestMonth' referenced before assignment`:

```
lowestMonth = 0
```

Notice, that by initializing `lowestMonthly` to `0`, you will most likely never get a correct result, since it is highly unlikely that any month has less rainfall.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. Still having a hard time grasping some of the concepts. Would you also be able to help out with this: I'm also having a hard time enhancing the code to sort the array in ascending order (alphabetical) and displays the values it contains.

Comment: [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted), possibly with a custom key-function? `sorted(['c', 'a', 'A', 'b'])` -> `['A', 'a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 2):

You have stored strings in your array rainfall, you need to convert them to ints before adding.

```
def totalRainfall (rainfall):
    totalRain = 0
    month = 0
    while month < len(rainfall):
        totalRain = int(rainfall[month]) + totalRain
        month += 1

    return totalRain
```